# angular array not outputting in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an array called reviews in my app.js file.
I'm trying to output the two hardcoded reviews on the screen, but nothing appears.
The error in the console says that the mainfunction is undefined, but I defined it I though with the correct syntax. Can anyone tell me what's the issue with my code. currently the page is blank and no reviews are outputting to the screen.

app.js

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/page1', {
templateUrl: 'page1.html'

})
.when('/page2', {
    templateUrl: 'page2.html'

});

$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
app.controller('mainController', function($scope){
$scope.reviews = [
{
    name: 'Joe',
review: "awesome site. Super informative"
},
{
name: 'Bill',
review: "Sweet site dude!"

}
];

});

}]);
```

index.html

```
   <html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="headerBar">
<a ng-href="/page1" id="page1">Page 1</a>
<a ng-href="/page2" id="page2">Page 2</a>
</div>
<div id="templateView" ng-view></div>

<div id="reviews" ng-controller="mainController">
<div id="reviewOutput" ng-repeat="review in reviews">
    {{review.name}}

</div>


</div>
<script src='bower_components/angular/angular.js'></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js">

</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Console Error

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ng/areq?p0=mainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at angular.js:68
    at assertArg (angular.js:1885)
    at assertArgFn (angular.js:1895)
    at $controller (angular.js:10210)
    at setupControllers (angular.js:9331)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9116)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8510)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8513)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8513)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8390)
```

Comment: That's the exact error? "mainfunction is undefined"? You are not assigning `reviews` to your controller. Instead of `var reviews =` you should have `this.reviews =`.

Comment: for the two-way data binding feature in angularjs, you need to store your variables in the `$scope` object. Instead of `var reviews = [...]`, write `$scope.reviews = [...]`

Comment: @RobertoLinares `$scope` is not necessary when using controllerAs syntax.

Comment: @Lex oh neat! I didn't know that, since the angularjs documentation only uses $scope; but you are right, you can use the controllerAs syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in angular expressions refer to attributes of the `$scope`. Not to local variables defined in the controller, which, by definition, are only accessible from the controller (since they are **local** variables).

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.reviews = [ ... ];
});
```

and

```
<div id="reviewOutput" ng-repeat="review in reviews">
```

Since you're using `controllerAs`, the controller itself is in the $scope, in a field that you chose to name `ctrl`. So the view can access the controller, and its fields. So you can do

```
app.controller('mainController', function() {
    this.reviews = [ ... ];
});
```

and

```
<div id="reviewOutput" ng-repeat="review in ctrl.reviews">
```

Comment: The OP is using `ng-controller="mainController as ctrl"` so `$scope` is not appropriate in this situation.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it. I've amended my answer.

Comment: I changed my vote after the correction, but I think it would be simpler and more correct to make reviews part of the controller.

Comment: I updated my code based on your suggestions, but the variables aren't outputting the review.name still. I'm also getting a controller error, which could be an issue, but I don't see anything wrong with syntax. I posted the controller error above with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

try this https://plnkr.co/edit/1zn6FLr8oRWHE9Y89k4z?p=preview

```
app.controller('mainController',['$scope', function($scope){
   $scope.reviews = [
   {
       name: 'Joe',
       review: "awesome site. Super informative"
    },
    {
       name: 'Bill',
       review: "Sweet site dude!"

     }];

}]);
```

if you want to use object in DOM you need to add $scope

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `reviews` array is private.  Attach it to `this` to make it part of the controller.

```
...

this.reviews = [
{
    name: 'Joe',
    review: "awesome site. Super informative"
},
{
    name: 'Bill',
    review: "Sweet site dude!"    
}
];
```